# NodeJS + MySQL, erro de conexão após tempo de inatividade

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

Olá, sou iniciante em NodeJS, e estou começando a tentar executar pequenos projetos. Estou tendo um problema de conexão com mysql, já tentei alguns exemplos, todos funcionam muito bem exceto quando deixo o servidor em execução e sem atividade em torno de um dia. Quando recarregado a pagina gera um problema de conexão, onde da erro ao executar a consulta sql porque a conexão com o banco está fechada.
Ideias de como resolver?
Vou postar abaixo o código que estou usando para isso.

db.js

```
async function connect(){
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
    if(global.connection && global.connection.state !== 'disconnected')
        return global.connection;

    const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: '**', 
        user: '**', 
        password: '**', 
        database: '**' 
    });
    console.log("Conectou no MySQL!");
    global.connection = connection;
    return connection;
}


async function sqlquery(q){
    const conn = await connect();
    const [rows] = await conn.query(q);
    return rows;
}

module.exports = {sqlquery}
```

Estou usando socket.io
index.js

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
            if (client.request.headers.referer.includes("tab")){
                (async () => {
                    const sql = require("./db");
                io.sockets.emit('/conteudo', await sql.sqlquery('select query aqui'));
                })();
            }            
        });
```

Erro reportado pelo nodemon

```
path>nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Timeline Server!
26/06/2023, 08:25:31
Conectou no MySQL!


26/06/2023, 13:00:53
27/06/2023, 09:37:23
path\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:93
    const localErr = new Error();
                     ^

Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at PromiseConnection.query (\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:93:22)
    at Object.sqlquery (\db.js:27:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async \index.js:60:43 {
  code: undefined,
  errno: undefined,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Vejam  que ontem dia 26/06 as 13hrs funcionava perfeitamente, deixei o projeto em execução mas não abri mais a pagina web, hoje dia 27 as 9:37 recarreguei a pagina e reportou o erro dizendo que a conexao estava fechada. No entanto, no arquivo db.js aparentemente só executa a query quando há uma conexão, mas não é o que acontece. Alguma ideia de como resolver? (vi exemplos usando pool de conexao, mas não cheguei a testar).

Comment: deveria abrir a conexão e fechar a seguir após executar qualquer comando no DB